# How to use perl code? Where to paste it?

Tags: perl

I was looking through google for a software that would meet my needs and found very short, 12 lines with regular expressions (whatever this is), perl code. The person who posted it is claiming to say, to others, that this code does what I want. But since Im not programmer I don't know what to do with it? I might need to paste it into txt file and save it somehow but the code is supposted to use text files. I don't think I would be able to use text files inside another text. My purpose is to filter email addresses from giant messy txt files. Im trying to use this code (but don't know what to do with it): http://linuxconfig.org/extract-email-address-from-a-text-file

Comment: Pay a programmer to do the job.

Comment: @davorg: it is a shame that something so unconstructive is also upvoted by the community. What a nasty people we have become.

Comment: See http://learn.perl.org/first_steps/

Answer (score 4):

You run the program using perl. Instructions for getting perl are provided at: http://www.perl.org/get.html

Then see [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/) for getting started instructions.

Assuming you are using a UNIX-like operating system (i.e. not Windows) the process is:

1. Put the code in a text file on a system with perl installed
2. Make it executable (`chmod +x filename`)
3. Run it as per the example under "Execution".

Answer (score 3):

Save the content to a file named e.g.

> extract.pl

And install per for windows: http://strawberryperl.com/ ; if you are on Unix, well done.

now you can execute the script by opening a console window, changing in the directory where the script is saved and execute

> perl extract.pl < yourtextfile.txt

Comment: What do you mean my text file? As I asked: I need to use in the  code the text file with which the code will be working - so the giant one with messy text to get out email addresses. How am I supposted to use your line of code then (only one txt definited)? OS is windows

Comment: The script takes a text file as argument - as the title from your link says.